# Call Transferring in Pjsip Android returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

My Voip Application using pjsua returns 403 Frobidden on Call Transferring REFER request.

The Call transferring code is as follows,

```
public void transferTo(String destination) throws Exception {

        String transferString = "sip:" + destination + "@" + SipPreferenceManager.getDomain(context);

        CallOpParam param = new CallOpParam();

        currentCall.xfer(transferString, param);
        }
```

The response logs are as folows,

I/System.out: REFER sip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5060;TRC=ffffffff-ffffffff;Dpt=ed2a-200 SIP/2.0

I/System.out: Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 25.45.1.121:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj1bb70192-a6be-4a2d-89bb-4bafc03af55d

I/System.out: Max-Forwards: 70

I/System.out: From: ;tag=2b62b4a4-31c4-42d4-b848-755d5f6e2a13

I/System.out: To: ;tag=sbc04074wqgc46y

I/System.out: Contact:

I/System.out: Call-ID: asbcyf4y5uw9ufr2yqf979gy2uguwr7e7f2f@10.191.54.18

I/System.out: CSeq: 13241 REFER

I/System.out: Event: refer

I/System.out: Expires: 600

I/System.out: Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

I/System.out: Accept: message/sipfrag;version=2.0

I/System.out: Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer

I/System.out: Refer-To: sip:123456789@domain

I/System.out: Referred-By:

I/System.out: User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.9

I/System.out: Content-Length:  0

I/System.out: --end msg--

I/System.out: 14:04:11.804 evsub0x8e7fbc1  .....Subscription state changed NULL --> SENT

I/System.out: 14:04:11.926   pjsua_core.c !.RX 348 bytes Response msg 
403/REFER/cseq=13241 (rdata0x8df74014) from UDP 218.248.233.142:5060:

I/System.out: SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden

I/System.out: Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 25.45.1.121:5060;branch=z9hG4bKPj1bb70192-a6be-4a2d-89bb-4bafc03af55d;rport=5060

I/System.out: Call-ID: asbcyf4y5uw9ufr2yqf979gy2uguwr7e7f2f@10.191.54.18

I/System.out: From: ;tag=2b62b4a4-31c4-42d4-b848-755d5f6e2a13

I/System.out: To: ;tag=sbc04074wqgc46y

I/System.out: CSeq: 13241 REFER

I/System.out: Content-Length: 0

I/System.out: --end msg--

I/System.out: 14:04:11.928 evsub0x8e7fbc1  ....Subscription state changed SENT --> TERMINATED

I/System.out: 14:04:11.929   pjsua_call.c  ......Xfer client subscription terminated

I/System.out: 14:04:12.086   pjsua_core.c  .TX 358 bytes Response msg 500/INVITE/cseq=1 (tdta0x8e0dc064) to UDP 212.129.25.1:5074:

Answer (score 1):

Use this code its works for me fine.

```
 if (currentCall != null) {
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
        prm.setStatusCode(pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK);
        try {
        currentCall.xfer("sip:" + transferNumber + "@" + serverAddress, prm);
        } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
       }
```

Thanks, Happy coding...

Comment: It did'nt worked for me..
Had u implemented Conference Calling ?

Comment: yes, I am implementing conference calling as well as call transfer.